# Download torrents on an iPad to a NAS

Tags: download, nas, bittorrent, ipad

I recently purchased the amazing TonidoPlug 2 to be a media server. Now, I would like to run a torrent client on my iPad, but save the downloads right to the TonidoPlug. The TonidoPlug has various connection options, such as SMB(which I currently use), and uPnP. Does anyone know of any torrent clients for iPad that can save somewhere other than the internal iPad storage?

Comment: Questions posted to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) should relate to **computer** hardware and/or software.  Please visit the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) for more information.

Comment: One approach is to install [transmission-daemon](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) on your TonidoPlug 2 and then run [iControlBits](http://itunes.apple.com/si/app/icontrolbits/id408490910?mt=8) on the iPad. I use this approach with my Tomato router and Android phone.